# My mouse has gone completely crazy

Tags: 11.04, mouse

I recently upgraded my laptop to natty, everything went fine and I have been using it for a few days now. However today the pointer seems to have developed a mind of its own. When I try to move it it jumps about the screen and selects things, and even when I'm not touching it it moves slowly to the left sometimes.

But the weird thing is it does not do this all the time, it seems to be doing it on and off, I just managed to use it for half an hour there before it started misbehaving again. I've re-started the machine, doesn't fix it. Also the problem is not with the mouse and/or track pad because I've plugged in various devices to test it and it does the same thing with a mouse, trackball and the fingerpad on the laptop.

Also if there is a thread somewhere out there that deals with this problem, just post me the link and a summary of the steps to follow. I looked and couldn't find anything on this specific problem but there must be something out there somewhere.

Comment: You said that the problem is happening on a laptop with a builtin touchpad: please, could you check that the option "Disable touchpad while typing" is set in the mouse preferences window?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)